Configuring paths TeXLive search paths for embedded fonts
The IEEE Access Latex template includes multiple embedded fonts. You can easily compile the template by running pdflatex inside the directory where you unzipped it. However, to work with the build system I'm using, I need to run pdflatex from a directory outside of the source directory, which does not work:
$ TEXINPUTS="./ACCESS_latex_template_20240429:" pdflatex access.tex
...
pdfTeX warning: pdflatex (file t1-times.map): cannot open font map file
pdfTeX warning: pdflatex (file t1-formata.map): cannot open font map file
pdfTeX warning: pdflatex (file t1-giovannistd.map): cannot open font map file

Errors follow the warnings as the font files can't be found. What TeX-related environment variables must I set to get TeXLive to find all files required for the template? TeXLive's documentation relating to environment variables is incomplete and confusing.

setting TEXINPUTS will probably work. But personally I would adjust the build system to switch to the folder.

It doesn't, as my example shows.

ah right sorry. Well you could try to set TEXMFDOTDIR, but be careful, that is used everywhere in texmf.cnf.
